# Retrieving specific images from Media Library

Tags: php, functions, loop, images, twitter-bootstrap

I developed a theme in which I show a Bootstrap carousel filled with sponsor images.
At the moment the sponsor-images are hardcoded like this:

```
<div class="item active">
  <div class="row outerDiv">
    <div class="col-xs-12 innerDiv">
      <a href="<?php echo bloginfo('url'); ?>/recruiting-messe/"><img class="carImg img-responsive" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url')?>/images/Sponsoren/PremiumSponsoren.jpg" alt="Premium Sponsoren" style="margin: 0 auto;"></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want my authors to be able to change the images without being required to dig into the code itself, but I don't know how to go about it. I thought about maybe retrieving images uploaded into the media library with a certain naming convention with a loop? 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You are currently missing two parts: storage and interface.

And yes, it would make sense to handle this via media library, in which case you will probably be storing attachment IDs.

Storage is easy, [Options API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Options_API) is trivial to use.

Interface is a little more involved. To this day WP doesn't quite provide a native way to easily build interfaces. Facilities provided are a bit low level.

You can use [Settings API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_API), but it's quite involved and doesn't get you all the way to form elements or media management.

You might want to search for existing frameworks/helpers, meant to implement settings pages.